# HTML Directory looking URL

Tags: php, indexing

My friend recently told me that I was able to do something like

```
http://example.com/about/
```

without having to create a directory and place a index.html inside of it, like this.

```
http://example.com/about/index.html
```

How in the world do you do this? I didn't know it was even possible to do unless you created a directory and placed a index.html inside of it, anyway thanks. :)

Comment: its called magic, or **mod rewrite**. you sill need a file to decide what what to do with the "about"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Apache as WEB server, use .htaccess for you site root directory.
Write following rule here:

> DirectoryIndex index.html

Also you can use more than one file here:

> DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

In this case first found will be used.

If you don't want to use .htaccess, you can setup same in Apache config file (httpd.conf):

> < Directory /foo>
>
> ```
> DirectoryIndex index.html
>
> DirectoryIndex index.php
> ```
>
> < /Directory>

Here /foo - root directory of your site

Answer (score 0):

Servers like [Nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule) can allow you to rewrite URLs, so you can place your file wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Apache web server then create a file named .htaccess 
and write code like below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?load=$1 [PT,L]
```

If this code when you type a url like www.example.com/about its doing to open your aboutController
Write aabout in this url  http://salopek.eu/content/28/create-a-simple-php-mvc-framework

If you does not use Apache or you want simple solution then then you can just create a folder named about and create a simple index.html or index.php file. Then when you type www.example.com/about
it opens your about\index.html or index.php file

I hope it helps